# How to store the contains of a dijit editor containing image and text in a database?

Tags: dojo, richtext

I am trying to make an input field which accepts text and image with copy/paste feature. I am looking for a way to save the contains of this field and then retrieve and display the same in non-editable field.

Can this be done with dijit.editor?

I appreciate any tip on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need more than just `digit.Editor`.

You will need at least something like:

- `digit/Editor` for the writable UI
- `div` for the readonly UI
- `dojo/request` for sending Editor value to backend and for getting saved value from the DB
- A server able to handle non static pages (like Apache + php)
- A database (like mysql)
- A backend API to save and read from the database